# Android Application Development Using Java or Html?

Tags: android, html, css

What is the best way to develop Android Application. Should I implement using java or using HTML or css3

Comment: What is the best way to make dinner?  Should I use the stove top or the oven?  This is a terrible question, because you don't give any information necessary to make such a decision!  Much more information would be needed if you were to get useful advice.

Comment: Terrible question . Do you mean you want to build cross platform applications for all mobile devices using HTML and css3 ?

Comment: Why should you use html while you have android's own sdk?

Comment: Sorry I think It makes all of you angry.But all I want to ask what people suggest for developing Android Application. If there any problem to develop Application in HTML and css3.

Comment: Shouldn't we be a little bit nice when asking someone to mention their requirements. @Hasan you should mention the platforms over which you are going to deploy your apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you want to target. If you want to target multiple platforms like `android,iphone,windows phone` , then you should use `HTML5 & CSS`.

But If you are only targetting android then java is a better option. `Java` apps are more powerful and fast.They can use the device's native functionality like camera,gps etc in a better & easier way, While `Html5` apps can target the multiple platforms.

In Html5 also you can use native functions like camera , gps etc using some third party libraries like `phonegap ,appcelerator` etc ,but performance won't be that good.